# Как запустить анимацию при прокрутке до определенного блока?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как это сделать с помощью jquery....

Пусть есть блок в середине страницы. В нем есть анимация. Запуск анимации у меня происходит после загрузки страницы, а мне надо на определенном блоке.

Понимаю что нужно на

```html
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //Код
});
```

вешать событие прокрутки до данного блока и сравнивать, но не знаю как...
Можно с помощью того же скрипта получить размеры блоков до нужного, сложить их и сравнить. Правильный ход мыслей? Или как то проще можно сделать?

Вот так правильно?

```
$(window).bind('scroll.once', function(){
height =$('блок1').height()+$('блок2').height()+$('блок3').height();
if ($(this).scrollTop()>=height){
    Вызов функции;
    $(this).unbind('scroll.once');
```

};
});

Comment: Можно сделать проще, если воспользоваться уже существующими библиотеками, к примеру - [jQuery.apper](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)

Answer (score 1):

Засуньте анимацию в функцию, переменная таймера должна быть глобальной:

```
var animTimer;
function animate() {
    animTimer = setInterval(function () {
         /* тут код анимации*/
    },1000)
}
```

А потом повесьте все на событие onscroll у документа

```
    window.onscroll = function () {
   /* считаем расстояние до нужного блока */
   /* 
      тут element - это ссылка на элемент, 
      при достижении которого нужного показать анимацию 
   */
   if(scrollY == element.offsetTop) animate();
}
```